# Ubuntu 15.10 freezes during boot

Tags: boot

Fresh install of ubuntu 15.10 64-bit on Dell Inspiron 530 with Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad  CPU   Q8200  @ 2.33GHz.  When I power on, I get the bios screen, then a quick flash of ubuntu purple, then it goes black and stays black.  Ctrl-alt-del makes it go back to the bios screen, then it gives me the grub screen from which I select "Ubuntu" and then everything boots up normally and runs normally.  Tried adding "nomodeset" but it messed up my monitor.  I don't know where to begin trying to fix this.  Thanks in advance for any help or insight.